# iPhone - Writing a custom text input?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, core-text

I spent about a week looking for any library or framework that allows rich text in a text input. I could not find any information so I think I'm gonna try to write my own text input.

Any suggestions on how to start?

- How can I display a keyboard for a UIView class?
- UITextInput protocol requires 35 methods to be implemented, where can I get information about there methods and their responsibilities?
- Any good tutorials on Core Text
- Please provide as much details as you can.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you've have not seen [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) ?

It's a complete drop in replacement for UITextView that adds support for Rich Text Editing.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great starting point, but requires a lot of work.

Comment: Doesn't have auto correction, cursor doesn't move correctly with 1 pinch, for a rich text I would like to have a menu where I can actually edit the text (bold, italic, etc in a UIMenuController), the code was hard to read because there are multiple classes in the same file, I need to add a couple of helper methods to pass an html strings instead of an nsattribute, etc. The biggest one is the auto-correction, I think that's a must have for any textView

Comment: Whilst I agree that the omission of auto-correction could be a stumbling block (*I thought it descended from UITextView so came baked in, but alas it does not*) the rest of your requirements would be fairly trivial to implement. For instance, you could quite easily add a custom view to the top of keyboard with the bold, italic etc buttons and then call the relevant methods to update the selected range. If I were looking to implement a rich text view, I would have absolutely no qualms using this as a base on which to build.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I really found EGOTextView useful, and as a matter of fact I started using it and building more functionality on top of it. All I meant by my comment was that this doesn't meet all my requirements and I need to implement more functionality on top of it, as well as fixing the cursor issue.